# Print the array index in variadic functions

Tags: c, arrays, random, indexing, variadic

I want to print the index in the array with random. But I can't.

Main.c:

```
RastgeleKarakter randomB = overload5_specifiedRandom(6,'g','y','u','c','n','e');
```

RastgeleKarakter.c

```
RastgeleKarakter overload5_specifiedRandom(int args,...){
  va_list list;
  va_start(list, args);
  char array[7];
  char* test;
  int sayi = (int) ((Now())%args);
  for(int i = 1; i <= args; i++){
    array[args] = (char) va_arg(list,int);
    printf("%c ", array[args]);
  } 
  printf("%d",sayi);
  va_end(list);
}
```

Out:

```
g y u c n e 3╝
```

I want this out :

```
'u' or 'g' or 'c'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> char array[7];
>   ...
> for(int i = 1; i <= args; i++){
>   array[args] = (char) va_arg(list,int);
>   printf("%c ", array[args]);
> ```

if there are too much argument you go out of the *array* with an unexpected behavior

very probably you wanted `array[i]` rather than `array[args]`, else there is no reason at all to have an array and it can be replaced by `char c;`

> Out:
>
> g y u c n e 3╝
>
> I want this out :
>
> 'u' or 'g' or 'c'

there is no test to write or not `(char) va_arg(list,int);` (forgetting the probable problem on the index) so how do you hope to not write all of them ?

Comment: No. I want the random character in the array. These array elements are " g y u c n e ".

Comment: @MuhammetÖmer why to define an array to always write the the same element ? read better my answer. ALso, what is _Now_ ?

Comment: Now out : 'a' . I want from between the characters I sent as parameters.

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: how can I say you while you do not indicate for instance what _Now_ is even I asked ? YOu will be disapointed but I do not have a magic crystal ball ...

Comment: This answer points out an error: *you wanted `array[i]` rather than `array[args]`* which causes undefined behaviour by writing beyond the array bounds.

Comment: Hmm ok sorry. I do not know English very well. Sorry. I get it now. Improved problem.